# Java socket Input stream read is getting hangs intermittently

Tags: java, sockets

We have client - server application developed using java socket programming.

My problem is sometime(intermittently) client is getting hang / blocked while reading data from socket input stream which making connection between client and server unresponsive. I have to restart either server or client to temporary fix this issue

The message which server sends to client is composed of two part a.header 
b.body

Header : my header data is plain and i retrieve header data by reading a character at a time from input stream.
Body :  body data can be in plain or zip format. I retrieve body data by either reading Inputstream or GZIPInputStream.

Comment: Do you have some code to share? Also, if you get an error message, can you attach it to your question?

Comment: A blocking read is totally normal if there is nothing to read. A Socket OutputStream does a lot of buffering, have u tried flushing (call flush()) when u have read everything the client should receive?

Comment: @Pieter I need to modify code before uploading it here.

Comment: @loonytune Yes i am calling flush() after writing message to OutputStream.